# The Love-Letter Mystery

Tags: beginner, ruby, programming-challenge, palindrome, edit-distance

## Problem Statement

> James got hold of a love letter that his friend Harry has written for
>   his girlfriend. Being the prankster that James is, he decides to
>   meddle with it. He changes all the words in the letter into
>   palindromes.
>
> While modifying the letters of the word, he follows 2 rules:
>
> (a) He always reduces the value of a letter, e.g. he changes 'd' to
>   'c', but he does not change 'c' to 'd'.  (b) If he has to repeatedly
>   reduce the value of a letter, he can do it until the letter becomes
>   'a'. Once a letter has been changed to 'a', it can no longer be
>   changed.
>
> Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single
>   operation. Find the minimum number of operations he carries out to
>   convert a given string into a palindrome.

The challange can be found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery).

## Input Format

The first line contains an integer \$T\$, i.e., the number of test cases. 
The next \$T\$ lines will contain a string each.

## Output Format

A single line containing the number of minimum operations corresponding to each test case.

## Constraints

- \$1 ≤ T ≤ 10\$
- \$1 ≤\$ length of string \$≤ 104\$

All characters are lower cased English alphabets.

## Sample Input

> ```
> 3
> abc
> abcba
> abcd
> ```

## Sample Output

> ```
> 2
> 0
> 4
> ```

## Test Cases

- For the first test case, ab**c** → ab**b** → ab**a**.
- For the second test case, abcba is a palindromic string.
- For the third test case, abc**d** → abc**c** → abc**b** → abc**a** = ab**c**a → ab**b**a.

## Solution

```ruby
T = gets.chomp.to_i
result = []
def difference x,y
  (x.ord - y.ord).abs  
end
T.times do
  string = gets.chomp
  i,j = 0, -1
  n = 0
  loop do
    n = n + difference(string[i], string[j])
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    break if string.length % 2 == 0 ? i == (string.length/2) : i + j == -1 && string[i] == string[j] && i == string.length/2
  end    
  result << n
end

puts result
```

Comment: I do not speak Ruby but I guess there is a way to write this in a more concise/beautiful way. As an example, here's what I wrote in Python : `print sum((abs(ord(s[i]) - ord(s[-i-1]))) for i in range(len(s)/2))`. Basically, you need to go through your list in both direction (and stop at the middle), summing the differences between the two values you are considering.

Comment: @Josay Yup, you got it. In Ruby it'd be `puts (s.length/2).times.inject(0) {|n, i| n += (s[i].ord - s[-1-i].ord).abs}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Josay pretty much [gave the answer in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55349/the-love-letter-mystery#comment97016_55349). That line of Python is even very close to Ruby's way of writing it.

Meanwhile, [ckuhn203 made a good point about the `break` line](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55359/14370) being obtuse.

Go upvote those two! This is just to provide alternative code.

Basically, you can do this instead:

```
# get number of words (T) and repeat that number of times
gets.chomp.to_i.times do
  # get word and map it to its ascii  values
  chars = gets.chomp.chars.map(&:ord)
  # print the sum of the difference between chars from either end of the string
  puts (chars.count/2).times.inject(0) { |sum, i| sum += (chars[i] - chars[-1-i]).abs }
end
```

Or you can skip the `map(&:ord)`, and get closer Josay's code by getting the difference as `(chars[i].ord - chars[-1-i].ord).abs`

Answer (score 10):

There is almost always a better way to loop in Ruby than actually using a loop. Unfortunately, I don't know Ruby well enough to say what that better way is.

What I can say is that this line of code is a bit obtuse.

```
break if string.length % 2 == 0 ? i == (string.length/2) : i + j == -1 && string[i] == string[j] && i == string.length/2
```

While it does seem to be a very Ruby way to write something like this, it's not very readable. Ternaries stretching off the screen are not a good thing in my opinion. It's okay to use an `If` block there.

Answer (score 6):

Others have already given you good advise about your code. I'd add that the problem is that it's too imperative (change, update, accumulate). That leads to verbose and non-declarative code. Instead, a functional approach using expressions and known abstractions usually leads to more compact, declarative code. I'd write:

```
nlines = $stdin.readline.to_i
$stdin.take(nlines).each do |line|
  numbers = line.strip.chars.map(&:ord)
  pairs = numbers.zip(numbers.reverse).take(numbers.size / 2)
  sum = pairs.map { |n1, n2| (n1 - n2).abs }.reduce(0, :+)
  puts(sum)
end
```